# Robot not moving to the goal - diff_drive_controller 4wheel bot

Tags: navigation, robot-localization, ros-noetic, diff-drive-controller

I am trying to implement the navigation and reaching the goal by the 4_wheel_bot, you can find the files in [this](https://github.com/Vasanth28897/my_4wheel_bot/tree/master) github page. I tried the `diff_drive_controller` by giving 4 wheel joints instead of two, which publishes the topic `/diff_drive_controller/cmd_ve`l instead of `/cmd_vel`, and it's totally working by just moving the robot with the help of `teleop_twist_keyboard` or `rqt_robot_steering` node. Furthermore, there are `amcl` and `move_base` package already implemented. But when i gave the `2d_pose_estimate` and `2d_nav_goal` in rviz, the robot does not move an inch. I don't know what causes this issue...
there are two launch files, have to run these on separate terminal... you can see [this](https://github.com/Vasanth28897/my_4wheel_bot/blob/master/bot_not_moving_to_goal.webm) video how the bot is reacting when the 2d_nav_goal given...

i am posting here the terminal results after the launch files executed..

roslaunch my_4wheel_bot navigation.launch

```
pc@pc-NUC12WSHi5:~/ros_ws$ roslaunch my_4wheel_bot navigation.launch 
... logging to /home/pc/.ros/log/b50f9400-a6e2-11ee-b407-7df1f70a5813/roslaunch-pc-NUC12WSHi5-74880.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://pc-NUC12WSHi5:33327/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /diff_drive_controller/angular/z/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /diff_drive_controller/angular/z/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /diff_drive_controller/angular/z/max_acceleration: 6.0
 * /diff_drive_controller/angular/z/max_velocity: 2.0
 * /diff_drive_controller/base_frame_id: base_link
 * /diff_drive_controller/commandTopic: cmd_vel
 * /diff_drive_controller/enable_odom_tf: True
 * /diff_drive_controller/estimate_velocity_from_position: False
 * /diff_drive_controller/left_wheel: ['front_left_whee...
 * /diff_drive_controller/linear/x/has_acceleration_limits: True
 * /diff_drive_controller/linear/x/has_velocity_limits: True
 * /diff_drive_controller/linear/x/max_acceleration: 0.6
 * /diff_drive_controller/linear/x/max_velocity: 0.2
 * /diff_drive_controller/odom_frame_id: odom
 * /diff_drive_controller/pose_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0....
 * /diff_drive_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /diff_drive_controller/right_wheel: ['front_right_whe...
 * /diff_drive_controller/twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 0....
 * /diff_drive_controller/type: diff_drive_contro...
 * /diff_drive_controller/wheel_radius: 0.025
 * /diff_drive_controller/wheel_separation: 0.125
 * /gazebo/enable_ros_network: True
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/front_left_wheel_joint/d: 10.0
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/front_left_wheel_joint/i: 0.01
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/front_left_wheel_joint/p: 100.0
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/front_right_wheel_joint/d: 10.0
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/front_right_wheel_joint/i: 0.01
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/front_right_wheel_joint/p: 100.0
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/rear_left_wheel_joint/d: 10.0
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/rear_left_wheel_joint/i: 0.01
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/rear_left_wheel_joint/p: 100.0
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/rear_right_wheel_joint/d: 10.0
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/rear_right_wheel_joint/i: 0.01
 * /joint_state_controller/gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/rear_right_wheel_joint/p: 100.0
 * /joint_state_controller/publish_rate: 50
 * /joint_state_controller/type: joint_state_contr...
 * /robot_description: <?xml version="1....
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0
 * /use_sim_time: True

NODES
  /
    controller_spawner (controller_manager/spawner)
    gazebo (gazebo_ros/gzserver)
    gazebo_gui (gazebo_ros/gzclient)
    joint_state_publisher (joint_state_publisher/joint_state_publisher)
    robot_state_publisher (robot_state_publisher/robot_state_publisher)
    rviz (rviz/rviz)
    spawning_lidar (gazebo_ros/spawn_model)

auto-starting new master
process[master]: started with pid [74890]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to b50f9400-a6e2-11ee-b407-7df1f70a5813
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [74901]
started core service [/rosout]
process[controller_spawner-2]: started with pid [74908]
process[joint_state_publisher-3]: started with pid [74909]
process[robot_state_publisher-4]: started with pid [74910]
process[rviz-5]: started with pid [74911]
process[gazebo-6]: started with pid [74912]
process[gazebo_gui-7]: started with pid [74917]
process[spawning_lidar-8]: started with pid [74926]
[ WARN] [1703920313.201055396]: The root link base_link has an inertia specified in the URDF, but KDL does not support a root link with an inertia.  As a workaround, you can add an extra dummy link to your URDF.
[INFO] [1703920313.361973, 0.000000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/load_controller
[ INFO] [1703920313.655122071]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1703920313.656130462]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1703920313.681551370]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1703920313.682233097]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Error: Non-unique names detected in <link name='link'>
  <collision name='surface'>
    <pose>0 0 1 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <box>
        <size>1.5 0.8 0.03</size>
      </box>
    </geometry>
    <surface>
      <friction>
        <ode>
          <mu>0.6</mu>
          <mu2>0.6</mu2>
        </ode>
        <torsional>
          <ode/>
        </torsional>
      </friction>
      <contact>
        <ode/>
      </contact>
      <bounce/>
    </surface>
    <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
  </collision>
  <visual name='visual1'>
    <pose>0 0 1 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <box>
        <size>1.4 0.8 0.04</size>
      </box>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        <name>Gazebo/Wood</name>
      </script>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision name='front_left_leg'>
    <pose>0.68 0.38 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.02</radius>
        <length>1</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
    <surface>
      <contact>
        <ode/>
      </contact>
      <bounce/>
      <friction>
        <torsional>
          <ode/>
        </torsional>
        <ode/>
      </friction>
    </surface>
  </collision>
  <visual name='front_left_leg'>
    <pose>0.68 0.38 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.02</radius>
        <length>1</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
      </script>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision name='front_right_leg'>
    <pose>0.68 -0.38 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.02</radius>
        <length>1</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
    <surface>
      <contact>
        <ode/>
      </contact>
      <bounce/>
      <friction>
        <torsional>
          <ode/>
        </torsional>
        <ode/>
      </friction>
    </surface>
  </collision>
  <visual name='front_right_leg'>
    <pose>0.68 -0.38 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.02</radius>
        <length>1</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
      </script>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision name='back_right_leg'>
    <pose>-0.68 -0.38 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.02</radius>
        <length>1</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
    <surface>
      <contact>
        <ode/>
      </contact>
      <bounce/>
      <friction>
        <torsional>
          <ode/>
        </torsional>
        <ode/>
      </friction>
    </surface>
  </collision>
  <visual name='back_right_leg'>
    <pose>-0.68 -0.38 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.02</radius>
        <length>1</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
      </script>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision name='back_left_leg'>
    <pose>-0.68 0.38 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.02</radius>
        <length>1</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <max_contacts>10</max_contacts>
    <surface>
      <contact>
        <ode/>
      </contact>
      <bounce/>
      <friction>
        <torsional>
          <ode/>
        </torsional>
        <ode/>
      </friction>
    </surface>
  </collision>
  <visual name='back_left_leg'>
    <pose>-0.68 0.38 0.5 0 -0 0</pose>
    <geometry>
      <cylinder>
        <radius>0.02</radius>
        <length>1</length>
      </cylinder>
    </geometry>
    <material>
      <script>
        <uri>file://media/materials/scripts/gazebo.material</uri>
        <name>Gazebo/Grey</name>
      </script>
    </material>
  </visual>
  <self_collide>0</self_collide>
  <inertial>
    <pose>0 0 0 0 -0 0</pose>
    <inertia>
      <ixx>1</ixx>
      <ixy>0</ixy>
      <ixz>0</ixz>
      <iyy>1</iyy>
      <iyz>0</iyz>
      <izz>1</izz>
    </inertia>
    <mass>1</mass>
  </inertial>
  <enable_wind>0</enable_wind>
  <kinematic>0</kinematic>
</link>

[ INFO] [1703920314.132334676]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1703920314.152715158]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[ERROR] [1703920314.184128, 144.836000]: Spawn service failed. Exiting.
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2105: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.
../src/intel/isl/isl.c:2105: FINISHME: ../src/intel/isl/isl.c:isl_surf_supports_ccs: CCS for 3D textures is disabled, but a workaround is available.
[spawning_lidar-8] process has died [pid 74926, exit code 1, cmd /opt/ros/noetic/lib/gazebo_ros/spawn_model -urdf -param robot_description -model my_rover __name:=spawning_lidar __log:=/home/pc/.ros/log/b50f9400-a6e2-11ee-b407-7df1f70a5813/spawning_lidar-8.log].
log file: /home/pc/.ros/log/b50f9400-a6e2-11ee-b407-7df1f70a5813/spawning_lidar-8*.log
[ INFO] [1703920315.050990054, 144.916000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1703920315.054478329, 144.916000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ WARN] [1703920315.054523453, 144.916000000]: dynamic reconfigure is not enabled for this image topic [image_raw] becuase <cameraName> is not specified
[ INFO] [1703920315.062594749, 144.916000000]: Laser Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1703920315.062678021, 144.916000000]: Starting Laser Plugin (ns = /)
[ INFO] [1703920315.063889626, 144.916000000]: Laser Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[ INFO] [1703920315.169929579, 144.916000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
[ INFO] [1703920315.170051816, 144.916000000]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /
[ INFO] [1703920315.171993289, 144.916000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[ERROR] [1703920315.285361885, 144.916000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/front_left_wheel_joint
[ERROR] [1703920315.285814208, 144.916000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/rear_left_wheel_joint
[ERROR] [1703920315.286150395, 144.916000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/front_right_wheel_joint
[ERROR] [1703920315.286822565, 144.916000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/rear_right_wheel_joint
[ INFO] [1703920315.291574976, 144.916000000]: Loaded gazebo_ros_control.
[INFO] [1703920315.475831, 145.090000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/switch_controller
[INFO] [1703920315.484127, 145.095000]: Controller Spawner: Waiting for service controller_manager/unload_controller
[INFO] [1703920315.492859, 145.103000]: Loading controller: diff_drive_controller
[ INFO] [1703920315.519353393, 145.118000000]: Controller state will be published at 50Hz.
[ INFO] [1703920315.520722058, 145.119000000]: Wheel separation will be multiplied by 1.
[ INFO] [1703920315.523375624, 145.122000000]: Left wheel radius will be multiplied by 1.
[ INFO] [1703920315.523493837, 145.122000000]: Right wheel radius will be multiplied by 1.
[ INFO] [1703920315.524567966, 145.122000000]: Velocity rolling window size of 10.
[ INFO] [1703920315.526177505, 145.124000000]: Velocity commands will be considered old if they are older than 0.5s.
[ INFO] [1703920315.527602461, 145.125000000]: Allow mutiple cmd_vel publishers is enabled
[ INFO] [1703920315.529640837, 145.127000000]: Base frame_id set to base_link
[ INFO] [1703920315.531813692, 145.129000000]: Odometry frame_id set to odom
[ INFO] [1703920315.535220029, 145.132000000]: Publishing to tf is enabled
[ INFO] [1703920315.552850365, 145.147000000]: Odometry params : wheel separation 0.125, left wheel radius 0.025, right wheel radius 0.025
[ INFO] [1703920315.559993255, 145.153000000]: Adding left wheel with joint name: front_left_wheel_joint and right wheel with joint name: front_right_wheel_joint
[ INFO] [1703920315.560146106, 145.154000000]: Adding left wheel with joint name: rear_left_wheel_joint and right wheel with joint name: rear_right_wheel_joint
[ INFO] [1703920315.582658184, 145.173000000]: Dynamic Reconfigure:
DynamicParams:
    Odometry parameters:
        left wheel radius multiplier: 1
        right wheel radius multiplier: 1
        wheel separation multiplier: 1
    Publication parameters:
        Publish executed velocity command: disabled
        Publication rate: 50
        Publish frame odom on tf: enabled
[INFO] [1703920315.590121, 145.180000]: Loading controller: joint_state_controller
[INFO] [1703920315.613393, 145.201000]: Controller Spawner: Loaded controllers: diff_drive_controller, joint_state_controller
[INFO] [1703920315.624950, 145.212000]: Started controllers: diff_drive_controller, joint_state_controller
```

roslaunch my_4wheel_bot move_base.launch

```
pc@pc-NUC12WSHi5:~/ros_ws$ roslaunch my_4wheel_bot move_base.launch 
... logging to /home/pc/.ros/log/b50f9400-a6e2-11ee-b407-7df1f70a5813/roslaunch-pc-NUC12WSHi5-75267.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://pc-NUC12WSHi5:34391/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /amcl/gui_publish_rate: 10.0
 * /amcl/kld_err: 0.05
 * /amcl/kld_z: 0.99
 * /amcl/laser_lambda_short: 0.1
 * /amcl/laser_likelihood_max_dist: 2.0
 * /amcl/laser_max_beams: 30
 * /amcl/laser_model_type: likelihood_field
 * /amcl/laser_sigma_hit: 0.2
 * /amcl/laser_z_hit: 0.5
 * /amcl/laser_z_max: 0.05
 * /amcl/laser_z_rand: 0.5
 * /amcl/laser_z_short: 0.05
 * /amcl/max_particles: 2000
 * /amcl/min_particles: 500
 * /amcl/odom_alpha1: 0.2
 * /amcl/odom_alpha2: 0.2
 * /amcl/odom_alpha3: 0.8
 * /amcl/odom_alpha4: 0.2
 * /amcl/odom_alpha5: 0.1
 * /amcl/odom_frame_id: odom
 * /amcl/odom_model_type: diff
 * /amcl/recovery_alpha_fast: 0.0
 * /amcl/recovery_alpha_slow: 0.0
 * /amcl/resample_interval: 1
 * /amcl/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /amcl/update_min_a: 0.2
 * /amcl/update_min_d: 0.1
 * /amcl/use_map_topic: True
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_theta: 2.5
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_x: 3.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/acc_lim_y: 0.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/controller_frequency: 10.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/forward_point_distance: 0.325
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/goal_distance_bias: 20.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/latch_xy_goal_tolerance: False
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_scaling_factor: 0.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_theta: 1.82
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_trans: 0.26
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_x: 0.45
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/max_vel_y: 0.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_theta: 0.9
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_trans: -0.13
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_x: -0.26
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/min_vel_y: 0.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/occdist_scale: 0.02
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/oscillation_reset_dist: 0.05
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/path_distance_bias: 32.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/publish_cost_grid_pc: True
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/publish_traj_pc: True
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/scaling_speed: 0.25
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/sim_time: 2.0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/stop_time_buffer: 0.2
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/vth_samples: 40
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/vx_samples: 20
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/vy_samples: 0
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/xy_goal_tolerance: 0.05
 * /move_base/DWAPlannerROS/yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.17
 * /move_base/NavfnROS/default_tolerance: 1.0
 * /move_base/aggressive_reset/reset_distance: 1.0
 * /move_base/base_global_planner: navfn/NavfnROS
 * /move_base/base_local_planner: dwa_local_planner...
 * /move_base/conservative_reset/reset_distance: 2.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/cost_scaling_radius: 3.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/footprint: [[-0.2, -0.375], ...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /move_base/global_costmap/inflation_radius: 0.55
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/clearing: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/data_type: LaserScan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/marking: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/sensor_frame: lidar_link
 * /move_base/global_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/topic: scan
 * /move_base/global_costmap/observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
 * /move_base/global_costmap/obstacle_range: 2.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/plugins: [{'name': 'static...
 * /move_base/global_costmap/publish_frequency: 0.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/raytrace_range: 1.0
 * /move_base/global_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/global_costmap/static_map: True
 * /move_base/global_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /move_base/global_costmap/update_frequency: 5.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/cost_scaling_radius: 3.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/footprint: [[-0.2, -0.375], ...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/global_frame: map
 * /move_base/local_costmap/height: 6.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/inflation_radius: 0.55
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/clearing: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/data_type: LaserScan
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/marking: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/sensor_frame: lidar_link
 * /move_base/local_costmap/laser_scan_sensor/topic: scan
 * /move_base/local_costmap/observation_sources: laser_scan_sensor
 * /move_base/local_costmap/obstacle_range: 2.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/plugins: [{'name': 'static...
 * /move_base/local_costmap/publish_frequency: 2.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/raytrace_range: 1.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/resolution: 0.05
 * /move_base/local_costmap/robot_base_frame: base_link
 * /move_base/local_costmap/rolling_window: True
 * /move_base/local_costmap/track_unknown_space: False
 * /move_base/local_costmap/transform_tolerance: 0.5
 * /move_base/local_costmap/update_frequency: 5.0
 * /move_base/local_costmap/width: 6.0
 * /move_base/recovery_behavior_enabled: True
 * /move_base/recovery_behaviors: [{'name': 'conser...
 * /move_base/rotate_recovery_1/sim_granularity: 0.017
 * /move_base/rotate_recovery_2/sim_granularity: 0.017
 * /move_base/rotate_recovery_3/sim_granularity: 0.017
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.16.0

NODES
  /
    amcl (amcl/amcl)
    map_server (map_server/map_server)
    move_base (move_base/move_base)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[map_server-1]: started with pid [75291]
process[amcl-2]: started with pid [75292]
process[move_base-3]: started with pid [75293]
[ WARN] [1703920320.087000432, 149.521000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 149.521000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
[ WARN] [1703920320.087308022, 149.522000000]: No laser scan received (and thus no pose updates have been published) for 149.522000 seconds.  Verify that data is being published on the /scan topic.
[ WARN] [1703920320.087575174, 149.522000000]: Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: canTransform: target_frame map does not exist.. canTransform returned after 149.522 timeout was 0.1.
[ WARN] [1703920320.634357520, 150.058000000]: global_costmap: Pre-Hydro parameter "static_map" unused since "plugins" is provided
[ INFO] [1703920320.635526559, 150.060000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "static_map"
[ INFO] [1703920320.638619829, 150.063000000]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1703920320.844913921, 150.265000000]: Resizing costmap to 384 X 384 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1703920320.944919863, 150.364000000]: Received a 384 X 384 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1703920320.954511759, 150.373000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "sensor"
[ INFO] [1703920320.965097755, 150.383000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1703920320.981582065, 150.399000000]: global_costmap: Using plugin "inflation"
[ INFO] [1703920321.040844116, 150.457000000]: local_costmap: Using plugin "static_map"
[ INFO] [1703920321.049657182, 150.466000000]: Requesting the map...
[ INFO] [1703920321.051589890, 150.468000000]: Resizing static layer to 384 X 384 at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1703920321.153457904, 150.568000000]: Received a 384 X 384 map at 0.050000 m/pix
[ INFO] [1703920321.164096356, 150.579000000]: local_costmap: Using plugin "sensor"
[ INFO] [1703920321.173105716, 150.588000000]:     Subscribed to Topics: 
[ INFO] [1703920321.186462956, 150.601000000]: local_costmap: Using plugin "inflation"
[ INFO] [1703920321.247968935, 150.661000000]: Created local_planner dwa_local_planner/DWAPlannerROS
[ INFO] [1703920321.252109807, 150.665000000]: Sim period is set to 0.10
[ INFO] [1703920321.450377996, 150.860000000]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1703920321.452541383, 150.862000000]: Recovery behavior will clear layer 'obstacles'
[ INFO] [1703920343.108455716, 172.065000000]: Got new plan
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was totally my mistake. I remapped the `/cmd_vel` topic from the `move_base` to the `/diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel` from the `diff_drive_controller` in the `move_base.launch` file like this

```
<node name="move_base" pkg="move_base" respawn="false" type="move_base" output="screen">
    <!-- Other parameters for move_base -->
    <remap from="/cmd_vel" to="/diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel"/>
</node>
```

now the robot moves like a charm. Thanks for your insight @Russ76

Answer (score 0):

There are two forms of cmd_vel, the regular form and one with a time stamp. They aren't interchangable. Have you checked this?

Comment: based on the echo command, i don't see the timestamp. so, i think it's the regular form.

Comment: But there are two cmd_vel topics i can see in the `rostopic list`, `/cmd_vel` from the move_base, and `/diff_drive_controller/cmd_vel` from the diff_drive_controller node

Comment: If move_base expects the shorter topic name, then it can't connect to the longer one. They must match. The one from Ros2_control is time stamped, I believe.